# ¿Cómo funciona la función IN?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo el siguiente escenario, en el cual necesito ingresar todas las `UBI_ID_UBICACION` a un textarea, por cada enter el script reconoce que es una ubicación y añade lo necesario para colocarlo dentro de la función IN, lo malo es que se pueda escapar (por parte del usuario) un caracter que no sea un número.

Sin embargo, si uso la función IN, me da el siguiente "error":

```
SELECT
    STA_INV_ID,
    STA_INV_NOMBRE,
    UBI_ID,
    CONCAT(
        UBI_ID_UBICACION,
        ' ',
        UBI_NOMBRE
    ) AS UBICACION,
    UBI_ID_UBICACION
FROM
    cat_status_inventario
INNER JOIN cat_per_ubicaciones
WHERE
    STA_INV_ID = 1
AND UBI_ID_UBICACION IN ('6333dsds')
AND UBI_ID_UBICACION <> '0'
GROUP BY
    STA_INV_ID,
    STA_INV_NOMBRE,
    UBI_ID
```

Este query me trae el siguiente registro, lo cual NO debería de hacerlo ya que en el IN busco por '6333dsds', no existe esa UBI_ID_UBICACION.

```
-----------------------------------
    UBICACION   |  UBI_ID_UBICACION
-----------------------------------
 6333 BBB-1-6-2 |       6333
```

Lo curioso es que, si lo pongo de la siguiente manera `IN ('dsds6333')`, me trae NULL, lo cual es lo ideal, ya que esa UBI_ID_UBICACION no existe en la tabla.

```
-----------------------------------
    UBICACION   |  UBI_ID_UBICACION
-----------------------------------
      NULL      |      NULL
```

La ubicación correcta sería solo `IN ('6333')` para traerme el registro.
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][3]][3]

Como dato, todas las ubicaciones son solo número.

¿Saben cual puede ser el problema y cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: `IN` busca valores que coincidan con los descritos. Puedes introducirlos como haces o usar otra query que los devuelva. Poniendo un solo valor, es como decir `UBI_ID_UBICACION  =  '6333dsds'`

Comment: lo que dices no debería estar pasando, cuál es el resultado exacto de tu query?. También, si usas `IN ('dsds6333')` te trea `NULL`  dónde?, también postea ese resultado

Comment: Voy a añadir unas imágenes para que vean el resultado de las diferentes queries.

Comment: @Hoose Si puedes sustituir las imagenes por textos como tablas mucho mejor

Comment: @lois6b Listo, ya la modifique :)

Comment: cuál es el tipo de dato de la columna `UBI_ID_UBICACION`?. Estoy dispuesto a apostar que el tipo de datos es string de largo 4

Comment: Faltaria quitar las imagenes ya que es bastante redundante ver el codigo varias veces. En texto es mejor porque puedes copiar y pegar, si el vinculo de la imagen se rompe sigue viendose y ademas pesa menos para aquellos que usan mobile y tienen conexion lenta

Comment: @Lamak es INT :)

Comment: @Hoose bueno, perdí la apuesta. No me hace sentido que tu consulta se ejecute sin lanzar error. Estás absolutamente seguro?, puedes postear la definición de la tabla?

Comment: @Lamak Ni a ti, ni a mi, ni a mis compañeros de trabajo... Es raro.

Comment: Por favor postea las definiciones de ambas tablas

Comment: @Lamak ¿A qué te refieres con definiciones?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE cat_status_inventario........`

Comment: Alguna posibilidad de ver la estructura de las tablas?

Comment: Solucione mi problema, lo dejo como respuesta. Gracias por tomarse el tiempo a ayudarme a resolverlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución a mi problema fue usar la función CAST y dentro de ella el campo UBI_ID_UBICACION 'convertirlo' a CHAR para que a la hora de evaluar, lo tome como cadena y no por el tipo de dato que tiene por default (INT).

```
SELECT
    STA_INV_ID,
    STA_INV_NOMBRE,
    UBI_ID,
    CONCAT(
        UBI_ID_UBICACION,
        ' ',
        UBI_NOMBRE
    ) AS UBI_NOMBRE
FROM
    cat_status_inventario
INNER JOIN cat_per_ubicaciones
WHERE
    STA_INV_ID = 1
AND CAST(UBI_ID_UBICACION AS CHAR) IN ('6332xsds')
AND UBI_ID_UBICACION <> '0'
GROUP BY
    STA_INV_ID,
    STA_INV_NOMBRE,
    UBI_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Saludos, 
En tu caso el problema es que tratas de evaluar una expreción alfanumerica contra una numerica, por supuesto que no va devolver ningún resultado. En tu caso lo que yo haría es crear una función similiar a la que encontraras más abajo, la cual extrae numeros enteros de una expresión:

```
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS extractNumber;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION extractNumber (cadena1 VARCHAR(255)) 
RETURNS INT(11)
DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
    BEGIN
    DECLARE posicion, resultado, longitud INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cadena2 VARCHAR(255);
    SET longitud = LENGTH(cadena1);
    SET resultado = CONVERT(cadena1, SIGNED);

    IF resultado = 0 THEN
        IF cadena1 REGEXP('[0-9]') THEN
            SET posicion = 2;
            checkString:WHILE posicion <= longitud DO
                SET cadena2 = SUBSTR(cadena1 FROM posicion);
                IF CONVERT(cadena2, SIGNED) != 0 THEN
                    SET resultado = CONVERT(cadena2, SIGNED);
                    LEAVE checkString;
                END IF;
                SET posicion = posicion + 1;
            END WHILE;
        END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN resultado;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Seguido modificaría tu query de la siguiente manera :

```
SELECT
    STA_INV_ID,
    STA_INV_NOMBRE,
    UBI_ID,
    CONCAT(
        UBI_ID_UBICACION,
        ' ',
        UBI_NOMBRE
    ) AS UBICACION,
    UBI_ID_UBICACION
FROM
    cat_status_inventario
INNER JOIN cat_per_ubicaciones
WHERE
    STA_INV_ID = 1
AND UBI_ID_UBICACION = extractNumber ('6333dsds')
AND UBI_ID_UBICACION <> '0'
GROUP BY
    STA_INV_ID,
    STA_INV_NOMBRE,
    UBI_ID
```

Te cambié el *IN* por **=** ya que si evaluas una única expresión no es recomendable usar IN, ya que disminuyes la eficiencia de la consulta.

Espero que mi aporte te sirva. Te dejo un enlace que puede que te sea de utilidad. 
[Funciones para extraer numeros](https://rubenlacasa.es/2013/08/20/como-extraer-un-valor-numerico-de-una-cadena-en-una-consulta-mysql-mysql-tips/)
Nos vemos!

Comment: ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo sin una función? :)

Comment: El problema del usuario no es que no devuelve ningun resultado, sino que el resultado que devuelve no parece respetar la condicion que define usando IN

Comment: Para no utilizar la función, pordrías hacerlo con el convert de mysql, sin embargo solo te extraería los numeros si estan al inicio de la cadena, de lo contrario obtendrías 0 como resultado.